# Can I build openTok(tokbox) hybrid application with ionic framework?

Tags: ionic-framework, hybrid, opentok

I am building mobile app which having secure video conference. I found Ionic framework which can support corodova. Can I build openTok hybrid app in Ionic framework? If yes can I know what are the pro and cons or limitation over android and iOS?

Comment: Hi, Now I'm trying to use openTok with my Ionic 3 app. Facing lots of styling issues w.r.t. to aligning multiple videos and adding buttons in the video screen. Would you mind letting me know the approach that you used to integration ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes.

But as always, things are slightly more complicated than that.

WebRTC works perfectly fine on Android, so will work in Cordova or even just Chrome. However Apple's Safari (which uses WebKit) does not currently support WebRTC.

I have had some success using https://github.com/eface2face/cordova-plugin-iosrtc which provides a shim for WebRTC and allows you to use the OpenTok.js SDK on both platforms. There are a few pain points around sizing, and overlaying controls though.

There is also: https://github.com/songz/cordova-plugin-opentok and https://github.com/aoberoi/cordova-plugin-opentokjs which I have not tried yet, but should work perfectly well. I believe the former wraps the native SDKs provided by TokBox, whilst the latter uses iosrtc.

Comment: Hi @Michael Leaney, I'm using cordova opentok in my application. When I use official plugin from https://github.com/songz/cordova-plugin-opentok  it works fine on Android and iOS but I'm facing lots of styling issues(alignment of videos) when multiple videos are streamed. When I use opentokjs video itself not streaming. Can you please guide with the solution that you had used or came across ?

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to add an update to this. I spoke with a few (very helpful) people over at TokBox and they have forked and released an updated version of the Song Zheng's (SONGZ) plugin. We were having issues with the older reliance on the outdated version, but this one is updated to 2.12. https://github.com/msach22/cordova-plugin-opentok/

Although it is not officially supported by TokBox, You are no longer forced to use the older 2.8.3 iOS SDK!

Much thanks to Manik over there

Comment: Does this works fine without any styling issues ? which is associated with aligning of the videos ?

Answer (score 1):

Brad, thanks for sharing the plugin!

I've moved over the updated Cordova Plugin to the OpenTok GitHub organization as an OpenTok Labs project so please feel free to contribute!

The plugin is currently compatible with OpenTok iOS & Android 2.12.0 SDKs. I've introduced some changes such as `OT.initPublisher` not requiring the API Key (similar to the OpenTok JS SDK) and have added more publisher properties: https://github.com/opentok/cordova-plugin-opentok/blob/master/docs/ot.md#initPublisher

Here are some resourceful links:

- Cordova OpenTok Plugin: https://github.com/opentok/cordova-plugin-opentok
- Cordova Samples: https://github.com/opentok/opentok-cordova-samples
- Ionic Samples: https://github.com/opentok/opentok-ionic-samples